# Setting JPanel layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

(Say) I've created a JPanel with three buttons. I want to place the buttons as follows (I've done this using netbeans GUI editor. But I need to write the whole GUI manually).

[image]

Can some one show me a way to achieve this.

***(In words, I need to place some buttons right aligned, some other left aligned.)***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you want the *Configure* button to be as far to the left as possible, and the *ok* and *cancel* grouped together to the right. If so, I would suggest using a `BorderLayout` and place the *Configure* button in WEST, and a flow-layout for *Ok*, *Cancel* and place that panel in the EAST.

Another option would be to use `GridBagLayout` and make use of the `GridBagConstrant.anchor` attribute.

Since you're taking the time to avoid the NetBeans GUI editor, here's a nice example for you :-)

[image]

Code below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTestBase {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Will be left-aligned.
        JPanel configurePanel = new JPanel();
        configurePanel.add(new JButton("Configure"));

        // Will be right-aligned.
        JPanel okCancelPanel = new JPanel();
        okCancelPanel.add(new JButton("Ok"));
        okCancelPanel.add(new JButton("Cancel"));

        // The full panel.
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel.add(configurePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        buttonPanel.add(okCancelPanel,  BorderLayout.EAST);

        // Show it.
        JFrame t = new JFrame("Button Layout Demo");
        t.setContentPane(buttonPanel);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(400, 65);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aioobe, Thanks, while I try that, will you please tell me what is the best way to follow when building GUIs? I mean the harder way (writing the whole thing manually) or the easy way (like using NetBeans, which I found really annoying)... Or is there any third option??

Comment: Definitely writing it manually. Slightly steeper learning curve, but oh so much better code, flexibility and maintainability.